# SQL Server 2014 LIKE with 4 B wide character returns the entire table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, unicode

I am having difficulty understanding why a `SELECT` with a `LIKE` condition on a 4 B wide emoji (http://emojipedia.org/eyes/) returns all rows in the table.

```
-- The DB collation is Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
CREATE TABLE #Test 
(
     Number int identity,
     Value nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('c');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (''); -- should be http://emojipedia.org/eyes/
GO

select * from #Test where Value like '%%'
select * from #Test where Value like N'%%'
GO

DROP TABLE #Test;
GO
```

The result from the first select is the single emoji row. However, the result from the second select, where the string is marked as UNICODE with the N prefix, are all rows.

Why does the the second select match all rows in the table?

**Actual Scenario** I have a web application where the users can search a directory, and if they search for an emoji the entire table is returned, instead of properly matched rows.

```
ASP.NET MVC 5 web application <-> Web Api 2 <-> EF -> SQL Server
```

**Update** My test `SQL` is incorrect, as @deroby pointed out the `INSERT` statements should be marked with N'...' to be properly inserted as Unicode.

**Solution** As @deroby stated it seems to be a collation issue, changing it to `Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AS` seems to make things work as expected.

```
select * from #Test where Value like N'%%' COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets even more fun when you add

```
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (''); -- should be http://emojipedia.org/eyes/
```

Your first `SELECT` will now return both emoji records; even though they will look wrong. The reason for this being that both  and  are invalid varchar() values. So they result in some placeholder being put in the database (shown as `??`).

Now, if you do your inserts 'properly' and insert the data as proper Unicode strings, then things work out a lot better:

```
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (N'');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (N'a');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (N'b');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (N'c');
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (N''); -- should be http://emojipedia.org/eyes/
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (N''); -- should be http://emojipedia.org/eyes/

select * from #Test -- returns everything
select * from #Test where Value like '%%' -- returns nothing (because it looks for the '??' placeholder
select * from #Test where Value like N'%%' -- returns just one line
```

PS: that's how it works on my SQL2012 here (Latin1_General_BIN).

> > Why does the the second select match all rows in the table?

That I can't explain either; for me it doesn't. So I'm guessing it's a collation issue where these emoji are all considered equal.

And indeed, doing the test

```
select * from #Test where Value like N'%%' COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
select * from #Test where Value like N'%%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

shows that the reason needs to be looked for here. As for the why, I don't have clue.